# What does 有模有样 mean?

Tags: translation

Is 模 in this phrase mo2 or mu2? Literally, have mold/model, have appearance/shape. Does it mean something like takes shape?

Context:

Fire TV, which arrives after years of explicit rumors and intense speculation, costs $99.

数年来，关于Fire TV，坊间一直存在着各种**有模有样**的传言和激烈的揣测，如今它终于以99美元（约合620元人民币）的价格面市。

Or here:

最萌对眼猫咪穿哈利·波特制服 **有模有样** 图

http://edu.people.com.cn/n/2014/0316/c1053-24647134.html

Comment: In the first sentence, it means 'look/sound real'.

Answer (score 6):

模 is mu2 (some people pronounce it as mo2, but that's incorrect in this instance)

模样 is a common word in Chinese means appearance, especially referring to one's look.

有模有样 means has the look.

In the first context, 有模有样 means vivid and seems-to-be-true.

In the second context,  it means the cat has the look of Harry Porter by waring the Uniform.

Another 成语 with 模样 is
人模狗样.
It means something looks good from outside, but indeed is bad from inside.

Comment: correction: 模 is mu2

Answer (score 6):

`模` should be pronounced `mu2` in `模样` and words like `[X]模[Y]样`. This can be verified in any Chinese dictionary, references:

- [模 in Xinhua Dictionary](http://xh.5156edu.com/html3/12041.html)
- [模样 in ZDic](http://www.zdic.net/c/1/8b/152020.htm)
- [Q/A on Ciba](http://hanyu.iciba.com/a/20090914/2428.shtml).

In colloquial language though, many people read it as `mo2`.

`有模有样` means `looks nice/real/decent/authentic`. This word is used a lot for teasing or irony, like to say somebody is ludicrously pompous. It can be used as a genuine praise *only* for something still being developed, like to praise a student's work. It shouldn't be used to praise a real master's work.

For example:

> 黑猩猩有模有样的拆着礼物。
>
> The chimp opens the gift with a serious but pleasant look.
>
> 小王才学一个月钢琴，就弹的有模有样了。
>
> Although Wang just started playing piano a month ago, he has become fairly decent at it.

Answer (score 0):

It means your are mimicking some practices in a very professional way which you are not supposed or likely to be

Comment: Can you elaborate or give an example? The way you've answered it is a bit vague.